# Javascript to stop HTML5 video playback on 'injected' html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I know that are several topics resolved here that is very similar with my problem, but believe me that I try everything and nothing was worked for me.
So first of all, I have a landpage here: http://styvconcept.zz.mu/projects/ovidiu/index.html

On the portfolio section, I have cople of projects listed, when you click on a video project (last two), it's open "injected" a html file, that is showing the project details with a video playback too.
Below this details is a "X" button, when you click it will close the project details.
And here my problem come, the playback of the video is still running and is very annoying the sound from the video.
I want to stop the video playback on that "X" buttom click.
If someone can help me out of this I will more than thankful!

Comment: On clicking the cross, it appears you are just hiding the player container `div`. If so, you have to stop the player too. Just hiding element, doesn't stop the video.

Comment: Yes, I know that, by only hiding the player container the video will continue to play. But How to pause the player? I try serveral many types of codes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pause the video player when hiding the element.

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("player").pause();
```

jQuery:

```
$("#player").pause();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I resolved by adding into an onClick function to the "X" button calling the javascript code!
Thank you again for your effort, I really appreciate!